# Stringing together multiple OR/AND conditionals for if/else statements in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm a newb and missing something super obvious here, but am unsure how to go about this the right way.  I'm writing a basic text adventure game for homework and want to string together multiple 'or' and 'and' conditionals without having to nest a bunch of if statements in each other or create a ton of conditional variables.  I know there has to be a way to do this:

```
inventory = ['some stuff', 'more stuff']
next = raw_input('your move: ').lower()

if 'this' or 'that' or 'whatever' in next and 'item' in inventory:
    print "Done"
elif 'this' or 'that' or 'whatever' in next and 'item' not in inventory:
    print "you dont have the item."
else:
    print "No."
```

I've tried creating test programs for simple conditional testing, and everything seems to fall apart when I string together more than one 'or' conditional like that.  It always returns "True" when I string them together, even if NONE of the words are in the string. I've tried using parenthetical brackets to isolate parts, but it still fails.  There has got to be an easy way to do this that works.  I'm all ears, thank you.

Comment: There are many good explanations out there for this kind of question, btw - I linked to mine because it was the fastest for me to find, not because it's necessarily the best.

Answer (score 3):

The logical operators `or`, `and` are for boolean expressions, not for providing multiple arguments to the `in` operator.

```
if (('this' in next) or ('that' in next) or ('whatever' in next)) and ('item' in inventory):
```

Comment: Jonathon, I understand the flaw in my boolean logic, but I'm wondering if there is a way built into python that accomplishes this feat WITHOUT having to explicitly state every single condition as you have done.  This is what I'm trying to avoid, I want to find the elegant solution.

Comment: The answer this is marked a duplicate of has an elegant solution using any().

Comment: yes I am using it now, thank you very much.  very nice solution